# loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler keeps calling when return from background to app

Tags: ios, iphone, game-center

I have an app using Apple GameCenter leaderboard, when I invoke

```
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *leaderboardIdentifier, NSError *error) {
                            
// This section call after become active
                            if (error != nil) {
                                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                            }
                            else {
                                if (success) {
                                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                                    success();
                                }
                                
                            }
                            
                        }];
```

Everything goes great.

But, when I going to background and comeback and become active, the method invoke again and I didn't call it. I guess the Framework did it.

Why that?
How can I avoid that method call?